# What's the Unix way of handling split-tunnels

Tags: linux, networking, dns, vpn, unix-philosophy

I want to be able to control in my servers which programs are connected to the regular internet and the ones which are only able to communicate through a VPN, in the most minimal, versatile and secure way.

### Current Setup

I have a server, a Raspberry Pi 4B with 1 Gb RAM, connected to my router. The ports I have forwarded to my RPI is a Wireguard interfaces, *wg0*, which I use for all of my personal devices and a port for Transmission peers.

I'm running a few services on my RPI, some of which I would like to be routed to a VPN except (e.g.: Searx, Transmission), others to be kept bound to the *wg0* interface (e.g.: Jellyfin) and in the future some which I would like to be public by exposing the ports to my RPI (e.g.: Minecraft server).

Currently I'm using *UFW* as my firewall which doesn't block anything coming from *wg0* and the port for that same Wireguard interface and also the peer port for Transmission.

### My Goal

I would like to be able to find an elegant solution that would allow me to configure which programs go which way, so that I could connect to my server from my *wg0* interface anywhere I am, but some programs would then communicate with the outside using the VPN

### Research Done

So far I know that Mullvad VPN can be used as a simple Wireguard interface - [source from Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Mullvad) - and I would imagine that the same would hold true for any other VPN providers.

I also know that for some programs, such as Searx, offer the possibility of bindings the outgoing requests to a given interface - by configuring `source_ips` - but also binding the address to listen on a different interface - by configuring `bind_address` - which means that I could be able to redirect the outgoing requests through the VPN and access it from my *wg0* network.

It seems that most VPN clients already support this split-tunnel feature for an arbitrary program, which means that they can do something of this sort somehow (taking a given program off of the VPN connection)! And because they are open source, the solution should be known.

### My Questions/Concerns

Now let's say that I would do exactly that, binding outbound Searx to the VPN and web interface to *wg0*. This leads me to question 1, how would DNS work in this situation? Would all the DNS requests done by Searx be routed through the VPN? Would that be something automatic, manually configured or even might not be supported?

I also know that Docker is the cool kid in town, that allows users to sandbox applications in a pre-configured environment, which would allow me to force the network connection for a given container. This leads me to question 2, should I be using docker in this situation even though I have a RPI?

Due to performance, and out of minimalism, I would like to keep Docker out the question, unless I really have to, which leads to me to question 3, if the program doesn't allow any configuration, is it still possible to route that program to a given interface? This seems like something that Linux does behind the scenes, if we have multiple interfaces that connect to the internet, I would imagine that it's the OS that decides which interface the program uses, not the program itself. Who's responsible for that?

Obviously knowing that the VPN clients do this, question 3 doesn't make that much sense, it does seem to be possible, I'm just not sure how.

Finally, a more generic concern as question 4, does the program have to be aware of its IP address? Because Searx asks for you to specify an outgoing IP, not an outgoing interface. I would imagine that most VPN have fixed IPs and as such this wouldn't be a problem anyways, right?

### Small Notes

As I said I have heard of Docker, but I'm trying to avoid it.

I also heard about iptables, but I don't know how to use it, and I know that it conflicts with UFW.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't quite understand your question, but it seems you may be better served by simple linux [network namespaces](https://www.wireguard.com/netns/) instead of Docker.

Comment: @HermógenesOliveira Maybe I complicated things in my question, but I'm simply looking for a way to be able to create a split-tunnel in my server is such a way that some specific programs can only communicate inside the VPN tunnel while others are left using the regular internet.
If this is possible in some VPN clients for arbitrary programs, then it should also be possible to do it manually myself, right?
When it comes to network namespaces I have heard of it, but I have no idea what does it do. Would you mind providing a brief description?

Comment: Well, I think that the link I provided in my first comment covers your desired use case, unless I am misunderstanding something. Basically, you can create namespaces where specified net interfaces will live. Then, you can launch programs in those namespaces. This will restrict those programs to the interfaces living in the namespace. Since you want to segregate traffic based on application, I think this is probably the best solution. As you suggested, you could also achieve this by messing with routing tables and firewalls, but it would be way more complicated and probably less efficient.

Comment: ufw uses iptables !  But the incompatibility is that other means to configure filtering rules can collide with how ufw does.  I don't think you could use firewall-cmd to manage the rules for example especially adding extra ones.

Comment: Split tunnels are an inferior workaround compared to network namespaces that are popular on OS without them. Just create a namespace, attach the VPN to it, start all apps that should use the VPN in that namespace, done. Firewall rules are per namespace, if you need different firewall rules setup. Don't use Docker, it's for a different use case (and it also creates network namespaces, BTW).

Comment: @HermógenesOliveira Yes that's exactly what I wanted, great!

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for that additional piece of information, I will definitely try to create and understand namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Originally I solved it using [this guide](https://www.htpcguides.com/force-torrent-traffic-vpn-split-tunnel-ubuntu-14-04/) which uses iptables. This method requires creating a user whose traffic is forced to use the vpn, because iptables doesn't support per-application filtering.

When I migrated to Fedora I was concerned that its firewalld might conflict with this low-level use of iptables and I eventually discovered an alternative way of managing split tunnelling, with network namespaces. Basically you set up a network namespace, make the vpn tunnel its default/only route, and run the applications you want to keep private in the namespace. I think not having to reserve a specific user is a big advantage.

There is a [namespaced-openvpn python script](https://github.com/slingamn/namespaced-openvpn) that conveniently creates a namespace and runs openvpn in it. The docs for that repository are quite technical, but there's a [guide to using namespaced-openvpn for rtorrent](https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/wiki/VPN-with-Traffic-Splitting). Most of the information in it is applicable to any application, and once I'd read it carefully I found it easier to set up than the per-user/iptables method.